# With the Java High Level API of Elasticsearch, can I ask for a sort order through the SearchSourceBuilder query parameter, instead of its sort method?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I see plenty of examples querying *Elasticsearch* with some search requests such as:

```java
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder()
  .query(queryBuilder)
  .sort(new FieldSortBuilder("age").order(SortOrder.DESC))
  .size(size)
  .from(page * size);
```

But I have a need that the sort directive comes through the `query` parameter
(because our customer is telling us: I am the one who decide what I put in my query: if I would like some sorting of the results or not. And we are receiving from him his dsl query, only).

Does a way exist that allows to ask for a sort order to be chosen by the mean of the query content?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No

Long answer: The `query` parameter can only contain a DSL query, i.e. whatever goes into the `"query": {...}` section of the search payload and that doesn't include `sort`, which can only be at the root level, as a sibling to `query`, or as a query string parameter in the URL.

Comment: is then a way to generate a `SearchSource` object from a plain Elasticsearch request, some of the kind that works with a POST in Kibana?

Comment: Yes, using [`SearchSourceBuilder.parseXContent()`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/main/server/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/search/builder/SearchSourceBuilderTests.java#L191-L232)

Comment: Not yet. We are waiting the good time to experiment it.